# C# problem with flags

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, variables, enums

I have an enum (flag)

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None,
    Dim,
    Inverted,
    Parse,
    Italics,
    Bold
}
```

I want to assign two of the flags to a variable, like this:

```
var displayFlags = DisplayMode.Parse | DisplayMode.Inverted;
```

However, when I debug and hover over this variable immediately after it is assigned, it says `displayFlags` is `DisplayMode.Dim | DisplayMode.Inverted`.

What am I missing/not understanding?

Comment: You know you should have used bit mask values instead of defaults. Didn't you get that memo?

Comment: @ssg You know you should have used constructive advice instead of assumptive sarcasm. Didn't you get THAT memo?

Comment: talking about being assumptive, I was referring to the answers here repeating same thing over and over, not you. It was from the movie Office Space which I highly recommend. And as a final note sarcasm can be very constructive.

Comment: @ssg Ah, my apologies then. However, with regard to your comment about sarcasm being constructive.....putting people on the defense is always counter-productive, never constructive; a lesson many skeptical enthusiasts need to learn when teaching others how to exercise critical thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've missed assigning the flags sensible values, e.g.:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim = 1,
    Inverted = 2,
    Parse = 4,
    Italics = 8,
    Bold = 16
}
```

That way each value has a separate bit in the numeric representation.

If you don't trust your ability to double values, you can use bit shifting:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim =      1 << 0,
    Inverted = 1 << 1,
    Parse =    1 << 2,
    Italics =  1 << 3,
    Bold =     1 << 4
}
```

From the documentation from [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx):

> Guidelines for FlagsAttribute and Enum
>
> - Use the FlagsAttribute custom attribute for an enumeration only if a bitwise operation (AND, OR, EXCLUSIVE OR) is to be performed on a numeric value.
> - Define enumeration constants in powers of two, that is, 1, 2, 4, 8, and so on. This means the individual flags in combined enumeration constants do not overlap.
>
> ...

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: It should have said "bit shifting" - basically, shifting 1 left however many bits, to get the appropriate power of 2.

Answer (score 4):

By default, an enum will assign consecutive values to the members.  So you've essentially got:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim = 1,
    Inverted = 2,
    Parse = 3,
    Italics = 4,
    Bold = 5
}
```

That doesn't work for binary/flags.  So you need to be explicit:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim = 1,
    Inverted = 2,
    Parse = 4,
    Italics = 8,
    Bold = 16
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing appropriate values to your enum upon declaration:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim = 1,
    Inverted = 2,
    Parse = 4,
    Italics = 8,
    Bold = 16
}
```

Comment: Why does everything need to be doubled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the values of the flags explicitly.  As declared, Parse is 3, which is Dim | Inverted.

Try

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 0,
    Dim = 1 << 0,
    Inverted = 1 << 1,
    Parse = 1 << 2,
    Italics = 1 << 3,
    Bold = 1 << 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the enumertion values as powers of two:

```
[Flags]
public enum DisplayMode
{
    None = 1,
    Dim = 2,
    Inverted = 4,
    Parse = 8,
    Italics = 16,
    Bold = 32
}
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using flags, you need to think in binary terms so you should increase your values by a multitude of 2 each time.  For example, think:

```
0001 = 0x01,
0010 = 0x02,
0100 = 0x04,
1000 = 0x08
```

and so on...